# Datastax Cassandra connector throwing NullPointerException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, connector

I am trying to connect Spark and Cassandra using datastax connector.
Spark runs on local machine, Cassandra is on AWS.
I run it from IDEA.

This is my setup :
build.sbt:

```
name := "bubblical"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val sparkVersion: String = "2.1.0"
val akkaVersion: String = "10.0.3"
val sparkTestingVersion: String  = sparkVersion + "_0.3.3"

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % akkaVersion ,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json" % akkaVersion,
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.10" % "test",
//  "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.0",
//  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % "test",
//  "com.holdenkarau" %% "spark-testing-base" % sparkTestingVersion ,
//  "org.scalaj" % "scalaj-time_2.10.2" % "0.7",
  "com.datastax.spark" % "spark-cassandra-connector_2.11" % "2.0.1",
  "com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "3.0.0",
//  "com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "2.1.5",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.33"
)
```

This is how I try to use it:

```
package bubblical.db

import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

/**
  * Created by kirill on 22/04/17.
  */
case class Aggregation(apn: String, imei: String, download_average: Double, download_total: Double)

class CassandraAccessTest extends FunSuite {
  val url = "52.215.24.146"//config.getString("cassandra.url")
  val port = "9160"
//  val port = "9042"

  val conf = new SparkConf(true)
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", url)
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", port)
    .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "cassandra")
    .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "cassandra")

  val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "test", conf)

  test("Cassandra access") {
    val tableName = "aggregations"
    val keySpace = "bubbling_dev_test_1"

    implicit val sContext = sc

    implicit val connector = CassandraConnector(conf)

    val rdd = sc.cassandraTable(keySpace,tableName)
    rdd.collect().foreach(println(_))

  }

}
```

I get NullPOinterException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException was thrown.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.close(Cluster.java:1627)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.access$200(Cluster.java:1318)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.closeAsync(Cluster.java:566)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.close(Cluster.java:578)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:167)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$8.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:154)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$8.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:154)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:32)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.syncAcquire(RefCountedCache.scala:69)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.acquire(RefCountedCache.scala:57)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.openSession(CassandraConnector.scala:79)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withClusterDo(CassandraConnector.scala:122)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.fromCassandra(Schema.scala:330)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.tableFromCassandra(Schema.scala:350)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableRowReaderProvider$class.tableDef(CassandraTableRowReaderProvider.scala:50)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.tableDef$lzycompute(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:62)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.tableDef(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:62)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableRowReaderProvider$class.verify(CassandraTableRowReaderProvider.scala:137)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.verify(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:62)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.getPartitions(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1958)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:934)
    at bubblical.db.CassandraAccessTest$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(CassandraAccessTest.scala:37)
    at bubblical.db.CassandraAccessTest$$anonfun$1.apply(CassandraAccessTest.scala:26)
    at bubblical.db.CassandraAccessTest$$anonfun$1.apply(CassandraAccessTest.scala:26)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Transformer.scala:22)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anon$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:166)
    at org.scalatest.Suite$class.withFixture(Suite.scala:1122)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuite.withFixture(FunSuite.scala:1555)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$class.invokeWithFixture$1(FunSuiteLike.scala:163)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:175)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:175)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:306)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$class.runTest(FunSuiteLike.scala:175)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuite.runTest(FunSuite.scala:1555)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:208)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:208)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:413)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:401)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:401)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:396)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsImpl(Engine.scala:483)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$class.runTests(FunSuiteLike.scala:208)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuite.runTests(FunSuite.scala:1555)
    at org.scalatest.Suite$class.run(Suite.scala:1424)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuite.org$scalatest$FunSuiteLike$$super$run(FunSuite.scala:1555)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:212)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:212)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runImpl(Engine.scala:545)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$class.run(FunSuiteLike.scala:212)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuite.run(FunSuite.scala:1555)
    at org.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:55)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$3.apply(Runner.scala:2563)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$3.apply(Runner.scala:2557)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:2557)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1044)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1043)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:2722)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:1043)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:883)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2(ScalaTestRunner.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:28)
```

I found something saying that this can be about Spark clusters but I run on my local machine.

Thank you.

Kirill.

Comment: spark cassandra connector use port 9042... if you have not changed default cassandra port.... also spark 2.x has `sparkSession` as entrypoint

Comment: Are you able to connect to cassandra in AWS with cqlsh using host=52.215.24.146 and port=9160? As AWS EC2 instances may have too strict firewall/portmapping settings.

Comment: No luck.
The same with local Cassandra -  localhost, 9042 and SparkSession.builder().


cqlsh connects.